# I am not able to parse data from push notification

Tags: swift, firebase, apple-push-notifications

I want to parse data from a firebase push notification and data is coming along with "aps" and I am finding difficulty in parsing. This is the data I am receiving in push. I want to parse "PnType", "Pickup".

```
[
  AnyHashable("CustomData"): 
  {
    "PnType":"PnNewJob",
    "PnResult":
    {
      "JobId":1743,
      "JobRef":"CAS4491055071",
      "Pickup":"Basil And Bean Co, phase-7, Mohali, Punjab, India",
      "DropOff":"Elante Mall, Chandigarh, Chandigarh, India",
      "Cost":9.00,
      "TotalMiles":4.93
    }
  },
  AnyHashable("google.c.a.e"): 1,
  AnyHashable("gcm.message_id"): 0:1555505650971833%277c5a32277c5a32,
  AnyHashable("aps"):
  {
    alert =  
    {
        body = "Hellodrive Notification";
        title = "HelloDrive Notification";
    };
    badge = 1;
    "content-available" = 1; 
  }
]
```

**I tried parsing it like**

```
let customData = userInfo["CustomData"] as? [AnyHashable: Any]
```

I am getting nil each time.

Comment: I'm not so clear on the format of your JSON. would you mind running `print(userInfo)` and letting us know what comes out. That will make it easier for me to help you.

Comment: i got this by print(userInfo)

Comment: This is firebase Push you need to check in firebase document.

Answer (score 1):

I tried pushing the notification using [NWPusher](https://github.com/noodlewerk/NWPusher) app.

**JSON pushed:**

```
{
  "CustomData": {
    "PnType": "PnNewJob",
    "PnResult": {
      "JobId": 1743,
      "JobRef": "CAS4491055071",
      "Pickup": "Basil And Bean Co, phase-7, Mohali, Punjab, India",
      "DropOff": "Elante Mall, Chandigarh, Chandigarh, India",
      "Cost": 9,
      "TotalMiles": 4.93
    }
  },
  "google.c.a.e": 1,
  "gcm.message_id": "0:1555505650971833%277c5a32277c5a32",
  "aps": {
    "alert": {
      "body": "Hellodrive Notification",
      "title": "HelloDrive Notification"
    },
    "badge": 1,
    "content-available": 1
  }
}
```

Following received in `didReceiveRemoteNotification`

```
[[AnyHashable("aps"): {
    alert =     {
        body = "Hellodrive Notification";
        title = "HelloDrive Notification";
    };
    badge = 1;
    "content-available" = 1;
}, AnyHashable("google.c.a.e"): 1, AnyHashable("CustomData"): {
    PnResult =     {
        Cost = 9;
        DropOff = "Elante Mall, Chandigarh, Chandigarh, India";
        JobId = 1743;
        JobRef = CAS4491055071;
        Pickup = "Basil And Bean Co, phase-7, Mohali, Punjab, India";
        TotalMiles = "4.93";
    };
    PnType = PnNewJob;
}, AnyHashable("gcm.message_id"): 0:1555505650971833%277c5a32277c5a32]]
```

Now, i retrieved the values from `userInfo` using below code in `didReceiveRemoteNotification` method.It perfectly worked.

```
    if let customData = userInfo["CustomData"] as? [AnyHashable: Any] {

        if let pnType = customData["PnType"] as? String {
            print("PNType: \(pnType)")
        }

        if let pnResult = customData["PnResult"] as? [AnyHashable: Any] {
            if let pickup = pnResult["Pickup"] as? String {
                print("Pickup: \(pickup)")
            }
        }
    }
```

**Output**

```
PNType: PnNewJob
Pickup: Basil And Bean Co, phase-7, Mohali, Punjab, India
```

Comment: not working . control is not going inside if let customData

Comment: Are you able to retrieve any other AnyHashable data like aps, google.message_id?

Comment: if i do  let customData = userInfo["CustomData"]  then only i am getting this

Comment: but i am not able to parse data inside CustomData

Comment: Let me understand. aps, google.message_id etc are all outside of CustomData.right? If so, you can try to get the aps like you are doing it for CustomData.right?

Comment: yes aps is outside the customData. i got the aps data

Comment: the thing is data inside customData is in String

Comment: Please see the edited answer

Comment: again the same issue

Comment: I tried with NWPusher and updated the answer. Please see if it helps

Comment: Any luck for you?

Answer (score 0):

First of all cast `userInfo` to more specific `[String:Any]`, then extract the values

```
if let userInfo = userInfo as? [String:Any],
   let customData = userInfo["CustomData"] as? [String:Any] {
     let pnType = customData["PnType"] as? String
     print(pnType ?? "n/a")
     if let pnResult = customData["PnResult"] as? [String:Any],
        let pickup = pnResult["Pickup"] as? String {
          print(pickup)
     }

}
```

Comment: not working . not going inside customData